# Facing Error while Setting up Cron job in Magento 2.1.3 from cpanel

Tags: magento-2.1, cron

[image]

In error_log:
[26-Feb-2017 03:28:01 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Magento\Update\Status' not found in /home/-/public_html/-/update/cron.php on line 15

Comment: Try this: run `which php` in your command line and put the complete php path in your cPanel crontab.

Comment: can send me reference link